# Stuck on Configuring Spring Webflow on Netbeans 7.0

Tags: spring, netbeans, spring-webflow

am very new to java ee and am trying to develop an app with JSF. I tried to define my own flow definition "language" 'chuckles' when i realised there had to be an enterprise class plugin out there for the purpose. With the help of google, i then stumbled upon Spring Web Flow and the specs are exactly what i need. I am using NetBeans 7.0 and Glassfish 3.1. Now problem is i have spent two full days trying to figure out how configure the vrious components to work together. I downloaded spring-webflow-2.3.0.RELEASE. I am stuck on the next step. The netbeans 7 i have comes bundled with Spring Framework 3.0.2.RELEASE and Spring Web MVC 3.0.2.RELEASE.

If anyone knows of a good basic guideline on how to configure spring webflow to work with JSF in netbeans, please help me out. Hope i did not sound too stupid.

regards,

Comment: ma bad. had missed the readme about the ant build. have just tried to build with some errors. let me try to resolve those first. regards.

Comment: ok. am thoroughly lost. I thought after the build, i would have one artefact that i could add as a library to my project but i am getting errors when i run ant from the spring release bundle. first error is `code`Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in F:\Program Files\Java\jre6\li
b\tools.jar. Then there is a lot of verbose stuff and lots of this type of error `code` [ivy:cachepath] INFO: I/O exception (java.net.UnknownHostException) caught when
processing request: repository.springsource.com.s3.amazonaws.com

Comment: Ok I got some hand holding. Maybe there is someone out there as green as i am. check out this wiki if you are facing the same problems i was [link](http://www.installationwiki.org/Setup_for_Spring_Web_Flow_2)  http://www.installationwiki.org/Setup_for_Spring_Web_Flow_2